# Ordered print in multiprocessing (pool.map)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool

Im using python multiprocessing to speed up some tasks,
so i faced a problem which on prints doesn't go ordered and they come up not ordered instead.

**Code:**

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool


def run(n):
    sys.stdout.write('=' * 40 + '\n')
    # some task goes here
    sys.stdout.write(str(n) + '\n')


p = Pool(4)
p.map(run, [i for i in range(50)], chunksize=1)
p.close()
p.join()
```

**Current Output:**

```
========================================
========================================
========================================
38
39
40
========================================
========================================
========================================
41
42
43
========================================
========================================
========================================
44
45
46
....
```

**Expected Output:**

```
========================================
38
========================================
39
========================================
40
========================================
41
========================================
...
```

Comment: Why are you expecting these to come up in any particular order? The whole point of using threads is to let things run in parallel. If you want a mutex around the entire operation you can of course write one, but a simpler way to do that is to just not use threads and run everything sequentially.

Comment: No this is not my actual code, this is sample that shows what i actually want to achieve besides that im running some if else statements then print out the result and then move on to another stuff

Comment: @abarnert can you help me please?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why do you think this code should produce this expected output? And why do you _want_ it to produce this expected output? If you can't explain that, nobody can explain how to "fix" things, because everything seems to be working exactly the way you should want things to work.